# Question disappeared from my results

Tags: discussion

[Injecting jQuery using bookmarklet not working on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58470603/injecting-jquery-using-bookmarklet-not-working-on-a-page)

is no longer found when I use my bookmarked

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript%20or%20jquery%20or%20html

As I was writing this, I noticed the "unanswered" in the path but the result list I have DOES have answered questions, just not the one I just read. It has not scrolled off as far as I can see, since it is only 22 minutes old as I write.

Is this weird? The question is CN related...

The Question is upvoted and the Answer is upvoted but NOT accepted at the time of writing

UPDATE: I see the "What's the difference" in the screen shot below has also disappeared so perhaps questions with opvoted answers disappear after a little while and I just never noticed before?

[image]

Comment: Your assumption is correct. See: [Why does the "Unanswered Questions" tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18870)

Answer (score 3):

The query shows "questions with no upvoted or accepted answers". The question would be dropped from the list as soon as caching allowed after it failed to meet that criterion.

[image]